# How Can I Prevent Slime Barrel Pumps from Clogging?

Tags: preventative-maintenance, sealant

I work at a bike shop that Slimes tubes.  We have both pre-filled Slime tubes as well as a keg of Slime that we use to fill tubes on customer request.  Unfortunately the tube connected to the pump for the keg of slime seems to clog on a regular basis.  So much so that we've had it clog multiple times within the day.

Does anyone have a recommendation for preventing this?  Any special secrets as far as diluting the material or positioning/modifying the apparatus for the Slime keg?

Answer (score 5):

I have no way of knowing if this will work with Slime but I have done something similar in industrial applications.

You will need a "T" fitting and two shutoff valves. Install the valves on to the "T",one on the bottom port of the "T" and the other to a side port. Install the side port valve on the Slime hose as close to the pump as possible. Connect the remaining Slime hose to the remaining side port of the "T". Attach a compressed airline to the bottom port valve.

To fill a tire shut off the bottom port valve. Open the side port valve. Fill the tire as you did before. When your done shut off the Slime pump and close the side port valve. Open the bottom port valve and apply enough compressed air to blow the remaining Slime from the Slime fill hose. The Slime in the hose that is between the pump and the valve should stay liquid as it has no exposure to air.